# Word automation in plain C++

Tags: c++, ms-word

I'm finding resource which is about word automation in C++ ( Win32 API / MFC ) . But it's quite rare.

Are there a book or comprehend article about this ?. Thanks so much :)

Comment: I need more information. Are you trying to generate a Word document from your code? Are you trying to implement Word's spelling/grammar check in to your code?

Comment: @Ben Burnett: Sorry for late comment, what I want is doing some basic tasks like save/open/close/insert text :)
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Three links to get you started:

1. [Microsoft Support about Office automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776)
2. [Tutorial on Word automation](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/atl/tutorials/article.php/c14519/Microsoft-Word-Automation-Class.htm)
3. [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145573/creating-opening-and-printing-a-word-file-from-c)

Comment: I've found that it's really hard to understand VARIANT and COleVARIANT, it must have a book talking about this!

Answer (score 2):

This [MSDN KnowledgeBase article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196776) is a good place to start.