# Is there a dev kit/lib (written in c or c++) to write docx files?

Tags: c++, c, docx, openxml

Is there a dev kit/lib (written in c or c++) to write docx files?  Microsoft has a dev kit, but it's written in C#.

Comment: A docx file is just a ZIP of a folder tree containing XML files. Can't be all that hard to deal with, right? I'd guess that you only need a few of the XML files to get Word to open it. Most of them provide for metadata and support advanced features.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm probably going to end up doing.  I was just hoping that I would be able to find a comprehensive library (not via automation) that could do it for me...

Comment: does the below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Given the complexity of the XML schema behind OOXML (the Open Office XML file format behind .docx files), you might want to consider using a tool to help you create an XSLT stylesheet that can generate the required output XML. Then use one of the C based XSLT engines (XT or Xalan-c from memory) to do the transform(s) before zipping them up.

Altova's Stylevision looks to have good support for creating the stylesheets but I haven't used it myself. Might be worth a look.

[Altova StyleVision's Word XSLT support](http://www.altova.com/stylevision/xslt-word.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not a kit, but you can try the Word Automation Class, which would work for Word 2007/2010 as well. Details on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296610/how-to-read-ms-word-documents-using-mfc/3331750#3331750).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer directly but if you can't find one, can you just writed a C# managed com object that exposes what you need and then just call CoCreateInstance to access the type library from c or c++?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Microsoft intends you to do one of the following things:

1) Have your tool output / manipulate RTF files, which can then be read in by Word 2007.

2) Programatically invoke Word to create the document itself, using its automation API.

I don't think the file format itself is something they generally expose the API to.