# MS Word: Generate a formatted Vocabulary Quiz with variable words/definitions?

Tags: c++, ms-word, automation

I am trying to create a vocabulary quiz program that will allow me to enter various words and their corresponding definitions and then will put them in a random, formatted order and then print the answer key on a separate page, all in a Microsoft Word document.

[Here is an example Vocab Quiz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8pV3VNYE-nzX1ptVkRIVXVPSlE/view?usp=sharing) *(Please ignore the embarrassing mistakes on the answer key; that was an older version that I revised and corrected lol)*

I have some experience with C++ (no idea if that is relevant here), and would be willing to learn whatever is necessary to accomplish this task, but honestly I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: Non trivial and possibly too broad. The biggest sin is what have you tried and where are you stuck? That said, Give this answer a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145573/creating-opening-and-printing-a-word-file-from-c

Comment: Why does it need to be specifically a "Microsoft Word" file? .RTF is a lot simpler and can be opened by Microsoft Word.

Comment: I apologize for being too broad and not stating what I have done already.  Essentially what I want is a program that contains text fields for words and their corresponding definitions.  A user enters each word and its definition into the text fields and presses a finish button.  The program then puts the definitions in random order, creates an answer key, and then outputs everything into a formatted text document. I have a program that writes to a .txt document, but I have no idea how to write it to a file type that allows formatting (or how to apply said formatting).

Comment: Apologies for the double comment, I ran out of characters on the previous post. As long as the document can be opened by MS Word and does not have any issues achieving the text formatting desired, the file type does not matter.